# CUDA code hang on Windows 10

Tags: cuda, gpu

I recently got a new machine with dual Quadro P5000 GPUs and Windows 10.

However, my CUDA processes sometimes just hang there and GPU usage drops to 0%.
I've tried CUDA 9.0 and CUDA 8.0, and both gave me same behavior.

I never had this issue on my previous machine which has Windows 7/CUDA 8.0. I am not sure what happened. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: When it hangs, have you tried attaching to the process with a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out it is due to "QuickEdit" feature on Windows 10...
"...whenever you click on a command window in windows 10, it immediately halts the application process when it attempts to write to the console...."

The solution is here:
[Why is my command prompt freezing on windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10)

Thanks!