# C# Log and Code stopping working, how to fix?

Tags: c#

This code has the function of:
each time (2 seconds) to consult two APIs obtaining bitcoin prices and finding possible arbitrage opportunities, later buying at the lower price and selling at a higher price.

It is a simple program, but after a while running it simply stops showing messages on the screen, returning to show after clicking Enter or something like that.

Running on Windows 10, one of the pre-requisites is Net Framework 4.6.1 which is up and running.

```
    static Object objLock = new Object();
    public static void log(string value)
    {
        value = "[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "]  " + value;

        lock (objLock)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);

            try
            {

                    System.IO.StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Program.location + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_logger.txt", true);
                    w.WriteLine(value);
                    w.Close();
                    w.Dispose();
                    w = null;

            }
            catch
            { }
        }
```

}

More: https://github.com/vitorgamer58/ArbitragemNacional

`[09/06/2019 21:29:20]  -4,71% BRAZILIEX > BITCOINTRADE`

`[09/06/2019 21:29:22]  0,47% BITCOINTRADE > BRAZILIEX`

`[09/06/2019 21:29:25]  0,47% BITCOINTRADE > BRAZILIEX`

`[09/06/2019 21:29:25]  -4,71% BRAZILIEX > BITCOINTRADE`

After Clicking enter, it started working

`[09/06/2019 21:48:30]  -4,70% BRAZILIEX > BITCOINTRADE`

`[09/06/2019 21:48:30]  0,67% BITCOINTRADE > BRAZILIEX`

`[09/06/2019 21:48:33]  -4,70% BRAZILIEX > BITCOINTRADE`

`[09/06/2019 21:48:34]  0,67% BITCOINTRADE > BRAZILIEX`

`[09/06/2019 21:48:37]  0,67% BITCOINTRADE > BRAZILIEX`

Comment: `catch { }` is a one way street to a vexing problem that you cant figure out, as you have no idea if there is an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my command prompt freezing on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10)

Comment: You should never ever ever write `try { ... } catch { }`. Take out that code and try again. Without exception handling you might be able to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @RobertBaron - Why do you think that is a duplicate?

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome here too.

Comment: Very Thank you, disable QuickEdit mode apparently did not solve the problem, i will try remove Catch and try again.

Comment: i remove catch { } and get this error: CS1524  C# Expected catch or finally