# Command prompt doesn't refresh on its own

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bat file which invokes a program with bunch of arguments.

```
start program.exe arg1 2 3
```

Now `program.exe` takes a long time to execute, *(about 2-4 hours)*.

When the program is done running, it usually prints the return code and execution times in console. But sometimes I have to press the return key in the console window and then I see the program output.

No idea why is that?

Comment: I guess that's not a problem with your code. Do you have QuickEdit mode enabled?

Comment: Using `start` without the `/WAIT` option just *starts* `program.exe` but does not wait until it is finished...

Comment: @stephan yeah that seems to have fixed it. I was not aware of this bug/feature. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10) worked for me. Which is,

1. Open `cmd.exe` and click on the icon in the top left corner to get the cmd context menu.
2. Choose `Properties` at the bottom of the context menu, and on the dialog select the first tab: `Options`.
3. Uncheck the `QuickEdit Mode`.