# How to let cmd-line continuous print log message?

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pyqt5

I wrote a simple app that I want to print logging message every seconds.
I open a terminal and run it, it works well. But when I use mouse to click the terminal, it will not print logging message unless I print `Enter` in the terminal.

**The Code**

```py
import logging
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


app = QCoreApplication([])

timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000)
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: logging.info("abc"))
timer.start()

app.exec()
```

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes,I use win10 system.

Comment: As explained in the other comment, the problem is not related to PyQt, but to the Windows command prompt: [Why is my command prompt freezing on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33883530). Disable that feature, and the output won't be blocked anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be environment issue.
Below example demonstrates that Qt logging works fine even if mouse button is pressed.

```
cat pyqt_logging_ex.py
#!/usr/bin/python3.9
import logging,os
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from pynput import mouse,keyboard

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print("Mouse click")

def on_press(key):
    print("Key pressed, exiting")
    os._exit(0)

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
print("Started listeners")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
app = QCoreApplication([])
timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000)
timer.timeout.connect(lambda: logging.info("abc"))
timer.start()
app.exec()
```

Run example:

```
pyqt_logging_ex.py
Started listeners
INFO:root:abc
INFO:root:abc
INFO:root:abc
Mouse click
Mouse click
INFO:root:abc
INFO:root:abc
Mouse click
Mouse click
INFO:root:abc
INFO:root:abc
qKey pressed, exiting
```

My environment:

```
uname -or ; lsb_release -d ; python3.9 --version
4.4.0-19041-Microsoft GNU/Linux
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Python 3.9.5
```

Comment: Your solution filter windows mouse and key event, Thanks for your  help.

Comment: If the OP is using the Windows' command prompt, then it's due a "feature": see [Why is my command prompt freezing on Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33883530)

Comment: I'm familiar with this "feature". It is not relevant for my answer, as I'm using X terminal. It is a good question, as operating system type has not been mentioned in the issue description.

Comment: @DmitryMesserman since it's unlikely that this behavior would happen on Linux, I supposed the problem was related to that, and the OP just confirmed it in the comment to the question.