# What could be causing server freezes in AzerothCore, even when no players are connected?

Tags: azerothcore

I am experiencing worldserver hangs/freezes which are only being detected by the frozen thread whenever I have the worldserver client in focus and send an empty line to the console.

Similarly, the server only seems to "update" that it has crashed once these empty lines are sent.

These crashes are intermittent and can occur whenever the server is left on for an extended period of time (such as when I go to sleep) and when I come back to the PC after 8-9 hours and send a line to the console, the server realizes it is frozen and crashes.

Small server with 5 players, no significant modules beyond
Autobalance
Statbooster

Freezes are occurring even when no player is connected, I have changed the `max_packet_allowed` in MySQL to a larger value. And help or insight on things to try would be very appreciated.

CrashDump with Debug: https://pastebin.com/7q6QvDZ2

`worldserver.conf` file: https://pastebin.com/gYrEjyHE

I have tried running a powershell script to restart the server whenever the `worldserver.exe` is "closed" but these freezes don't actually close the client because it does not realize it is frozen until I try to interact with it.

The expected behaviour is for the client to crash as soon as the hang-time is reached for the frozen thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe enter selection mode unintentionally when clicking the `worldserver` console?
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33883532/9446053) which explains the issue.