# Loop stopping in cmd until Enter is pressed

Tags: python

I apologize in advance as this is going to be a vague question. I just hope someone has the same experience and can help me. Imagine a simple script that has this simple code in it:

```
for i in range(100):
    print(i)
```

When I run the script from the terminal (CMD), occasionally, the loop gets stuck but as soon as I press the Enter key in the terminal, it jumps back into working and the loop continues. I want to emphasize that there is nothing like a user input line in the code causing a pause in the loop until a key is pressed or anything like that in the code. Also, this never happens if I run the code inside an IDE. This only happens in CMD and in possibly in any script that has a loop like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the command prompt it goes into select mode, you will see a white square. You will also see at the top of the command prompt it will say select. This will pause anything running in the cmd.

[image: Select Mode]

If you press enter that will get it out of select mode and will continue running the program

[image: Non select mode]

I believe this is what your running into.

Comment: Holy molly, I had no clue about this but I tested it and you are 100% right. Is there any way to disable that so that I accidentally do not pause my code like that?

Comment: Yep, found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883530/why-is-my-command-prompt-freezing-on-windows-10/76855923#76855923

Comment: @Saeed that is correct and I believe it only pauses anything that is writing out to stdout/stderr in the terminal. If I am not mistaken the program will continue running until it has to write to stdout/stderr and then halt there until you leave select mode.